# Phonegap page load again after alert (Android)

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, cordova

I have a phonegap application. 
There is one html file that is "index.html" that divided to some divs. 
each div is acting like a page.

The main page (div) is login page, which have input texts for user name and password, login button and register button for those who need to register.

When the user doesn't enter one of the fields and presses the login button, the app notifies him that he forgot to enter one of the fields, but in the background I see that it loads the page again.. 
and when I press "back" button from the android device, it shows me the first page when the user enter some details.

Another thing is when the user press on the registration button it's navigate to the register div which his id is "registerPage" , now when the user enters an invalid input in one of the fields, the app alerts him something but in the background I see that it loads again the main page instead of staying in the same div.. so what I did is when the user doesn't enter a valid input , I use `"$.mobile.navigate("#registerPage")` in order to stay in the same div of the registration, but now it loads the main page and after that goes to the register div.

how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the navigate is reloading the page.

Consider switching the divs in, (similar to using handlebars templates, without using handlebars :-) e.g.

in your html:

```
<body>
<div id="replacablediv" />
<script id="subheader-tpl" type="text/html">
        <div class='subheader' id="subheaderdiv2">Status...</div>
</script>
</body>
```

elsewhere you'd have a div that you can replace, e.g. in jquery:

```
$('#replacablediv').html($('#subheader-tpl'));
```

So instead of navigating to a div, you replace a visible div with one set inside a script template block. That would avoid any reloading of the page. (if not using jquery, you can use getElementById() to get to the divs/scripts.

Comment: sorry for not being replying for a while, so you suggest to replace the "view" ? can you post a full and simple example? thanks +1

Comment: The example is the second bit of code, that gets the html contained in the script and puts it inside the "replaceablediv" div.